# Using variables instead of arguments: a bad practice?

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have two buttons, one for “morning” and other for “evening”, and I want to `console.log` “good morning” or “good evening” depending on the button clicked. This is the way I used to do it before studying Javascript:

```
var greeting;

//"d3.select" is just a selection using D3
d3.select("#button1").on("click", function(){
    greeting = "morning";
    hello();
});

d3.select("#button2").on("click", function(){
    greeting = "evening";
    hello();
});

function hello(){
    console.log("good " + greeting);
}
```

Using parameters and arguments, this code does the same:

```
d3.select("#button1").on("click", function(){
    hello("morning");
});

d3.select("#button2").on("click", function(){
    hello("evening");
});

function hello(greeting){
    console.log("good " + greeting);
}
```

As far as I can see, “my way” is worse because it’s a bit longer and uses variables that must be global (or at least one level above the function). But, besides that, I’d like to ask you:

1. **Efficiency**: Is one of the examples faster than other? Is there any advantage using one or other way?
2. **Readability**: I know that arguments are way more common, but is “my way” understandable? Is it too strange?
3. Is this a bad way to code?

NOTE: Feel free to tag this as a duplicate, but I searched a lot and didn’t find this specific issue: it's not about using variables as arguments, but using variables *instead of* arguments. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, It is a bad practice..The simple reason could be use of `global variables`, you should avoid using them...

Comment: In addition to @RayonDabre's comment, your way is also much harder to understand, because "your way" code manipulates data from "who knows where". It is impossible to say when and where that data is getting manipulated, making it pure hell to debug.

Comment: The second way calls hello() immediately, *not* in response to the click events. But aside from that, yes, you should use function arguments.

Comment: As you become a more experienced develoepr, you will find that independent functions that carry out an operation based purely on the arguments passed to them and are NOT dependent upon external or global state are **way, way easier to test, maintain, debug, share, optimize, isolate from conflicts with other code etc...  Way, way easier.**  The difference is so night and day that you should never write code like your first option.  It's just considered a very poor practice and for very good reason.

Comment: FYI, your second option is not coded correctly either, it needs to be something like this:  `d3.select(“#button2”).on("click", function() {hello(“evening”)});`  You have to pass a function reference as the click handler, whereas your code was immediately executing `hello(...)` and passing the return result of that function as the click handler - not what you want.  You  also have to use real double quotes around your strings, not the fancy word processor types.  Never, ever write code in a word processor.  Only use a text editor designed for coding.

Comment: Thanks, @jfriend00 for noticing the quotes, I already edited it. I always use Sublime 2 for writing code, but this time I used a word processor to check the spelling before asking here (I'm not a native english speaker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

overall, the way you're doing it, (with global variables) is generally bad practice, but if you take it out of the global scope it can actually be pretty handy. read up on oop and you'll surely come across something like this.

```
function person(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.color;
  this.greeting = function(){ 
    alert("Hello,  my name is "+this.name+" and my favorite color is "+this.color); 
  };
}

var me = new person("James");
me.color = "green";
me.greeting();
```

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19ncmda2/2/))

in this example you have a variable set to the object and the functions of the object use the variable from the object rather than passing it as a parameter. this type of thinking will be helpful (and necessary) in object oriented programming.

also, just for kicks i did some benchmarking to see which method is truly faster. here's a fiddle that will test it for you. [check it out](https://jsfiddle.net/u2eoLc7L/1/).

Comment: Thanks, @yourmom, they both work on Chrome. And the performance seems to be pretty much the same.

Comment: I updated the benchmark script. i think this will measure it more accurately. you way is pretty consistently faster. @GerardoFurtado - https://jsfiddle.net/u2eoLc7L/1/

Answer (score 1):

The reason, its a bad practise is that in your first example, you are using impure functions, where a function is using the state of the program to carry out a set of instructions (In this example, its the variable - greeting).

```
function hello(){
   console.log(“good ” + greeting);
}
```

Greeting is a variable in a global memory, which means that hello performs actions which are dependent on a state.

Hence , when invoking 'hello', there is no way of knowing from the outside what the action the function will perform.

Always, use pure functions.

> Pure function is a  function whose output is solely dependent on its
>   input.

An impure function uses a state as a hidden input, which means that, the function hello returns different behaviour depending on the state of the program, which in my view, is not desirable when dealing with reusable behaviour. 
But pure functions, take all necessary variables as arguments, hence

> PureFunction(args...) always returns a value which is the same no matter what state the app is in.

**Edit :** 
A pure function does not indulge in I/O. I would still think, that using such an approach modularises our code better.

```
function hello(greeting){
   console.log(“good ” + greeting); 
}
d3.select(“#button1”).on(“click”, hello.bind(null,“morning”)));

d3.select(“#button2”).on(“click”, hello.bind(null,“evening”));
```

Comment: Sorry ... but as stated, this pure opinion.  WHY should you always use pure functions?  WHY is is "pure evil" for a function to have a behavior that depends on the state of the rest of the program.

Comment: @StephenC : I don't say that pure should be used 'always'. I suggest them to be used at times, when there is reusable behaviour. Also, debugging pure functions is easy.

Comment: I would also not that using the word "evil" is an explicit statement of opinion, because (frankly) "evil" is subjective ... not to mention irrelevant to programming.

Comment: So ... put the actual reasons into your answer rather than resorting to meaningless rhetorical devices like "pure evil"!  Also, when you use phrases like "pure evil" you are strongly implying that you think that X should **NEVER** be used.

Comment: Makes sense. Sorry about that. I did put an IMO before hand. Anyway, did the edits. Thanks for the feedback.